# Multiple jQuery/jQueryUI errors out of the blue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I coded my example site a few weeks ago. It worked all right, but now it doesn't. It started yesterday, after Chrome updated itself (or so it seems).

My errors in the console are:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rating'
```

Both of them caused by jQuery plugins I use all the time (jQuery Form, jQuery StarRating, jQuery UI, etc). Also, when I hover an element that uses `show` with jQueryUI, I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

My JS code is as follows:

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* T.O.C.

    1. Top
    1.0 | Header
    1.1 | Main Menu
    1.2 | Placeholders
    2. Content
    2.1 | Left
    2.1.1 | Box covers
    3. Sidebar
    3.1 | Rates

     */
});

/* 1.0 | Top */
// 1.1 | Main Menu
function searchInput() {
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var n = parseInt(0);
    $('nav#mainMenu ul li:not(.search)').each(function() {
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true));
    });
    var inp = 919 - totalWidth;
    $('nav#mainMenu ul li.search form input').width(inp);
};

function slideMenu() {
    $('nav#mainMenu ul li:not(:first), nav#mainMenu ul li ul:not(li a)').each(function() {
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
            var left = $(this).outerWidth(true),
                width = 0;
            if($(this).hasClass('help')) { // IF HELP
                $(this).prevAll('li').each(function() {
                    width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
                });
            } else { // ELSE
                $(this).nextAll('li').each(function() {
                    width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
                });
            }

            var width = width + 1;

            if($(this).hasClass('help')) {
                $(this).children('ul').css({ 'right':left, 'width':width });
                $(this).children('ul').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 250);
            } else {
                $(this).children('ul').css({ 'left':left, 'width':width });
                $(this).children('ul').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 250);
            }
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('help')) {
                $(this).children('ul').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 250, function() {
                    $(this).parent('li').children('a').removeClass('active');
                });
            } else {
                $(this).children('ul').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 250, function() {
                    $(this).parent('li').children('a').removeClass('active');
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

slideMenu();

searchInput();

/* 1.2 | Placeholder */
function Placeholders() {
    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){

        $("input").each(
            function(){
                if($(this).val()=="" && $(this).attr("placeholder")!=""){
                    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                    $(this).focus(function(){
                        if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
                    });
                    $(this).blur(function(){
                        if($(this).val()=="") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                    });
                }
            });

    }
}

Placeholders();

/* 2. Content */

// 2.2.1 | Box covers
function BoxCovers() {
    $('ul.boxlist li').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('div').stop().fadeIn('fast');
    });
    $('ul.boxlist li').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children('div').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    });

    $('.boxlist .rate').rating();
    $('.boxlist form.starRated a').attr('title','');
}

BoxCovers();

function Detailed() {
    $('ul.detailed .rate').rating();
    $('ul.detailed form.starRated a').attr('title','');

    $('ul.detailed li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('grid_4').addClass('grid_14 clearfix');
        var img = $(this).children('img').attr('src'),
            img = img.replace('.jpg','-m.jpg');

        $(this).children('img').attr('src',img).addClass('grid_1');
        $(this).children('div').addClass('grid_9');

        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).children('div').children('p.own').stop().fadeIn();
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).children('div').children('p.own').stop().fadeOut();
        });
    });
};

Detailed();

/* 3. Sidebar */
// 3.1.  Rates
function sideRates() {
    $('section#grades div ul li').each(function() {
        var percent = $(this).children('b').text(),
            percent = percent.replace('%',''),
            percent = (percent/100),
            totalSpamWidth = $(this).children('span').width(),
            newWidth = totalSpamWidth * percent;

        $(this).children('span').width(newWidth);
    });
};

sideRates();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer instead of a comment:

You are using the latest jQuery. This version probably has something removed or changed that you are using. I suggest you keep to the version you created the page on instead of fetching the latest. That way it will never break because of version differences.

Comment: $.browser is removed from 1.9. If you need, need to include jquery migrate script

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the fact that the jQuery.browser property has been removed from jQuery 1.9. Apparently this browser detection feature had been deprecated since jQuery 1.3, but many plugins/libraries probably still rely on it ([jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/), to name just one I like to use in my projects).

See: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed for official reference.

For a quick repair, use the previous version of jQuery, e.g.:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, but I've already got an answer :) Thanks for your inpu anyway!

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

This hints that jQuery isn't even loading. Check using developer tools (F12), network tab, refresh the page, and see if any 404 error occurs for any script/resource.

Comment: jQuery is loaded (using `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`) as the rest of JS.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski since you are always fetching the latest version.. Are you using something that is removed in the newest version? You might want tot stick witht he one version that works for you, since newer versions might break something.

Comment: If jQuery was'nt loaded, you'd get a `$ is not defined` error before anything else. And when linking to the jQuery CDN, it does'nt matter if it's on "the computer" or not? $.browser was probably removed in 1.9, and that's where the "msie" error comes from.

Comment: @Rune you're right! jQuery updated to 1.9.0 and that caused the problem. Please, post this as an answer so I can accept and vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error while still using the latest jQuery.  My call to the Superfish menu script gave me the "Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" error when I called it from:

```
$(document).ready(function() { startScripts(); });
```

But, then I changed it to:

```
$(document).load(function() { startScripts(); });
```

The error disappeared, which suggests that this is a load-order timing issue.